# Is there an alternative to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application?

Tags: telerik, office-interop

It may be a class from Telerik. It must not be assumed that Office is installed. So, I've to use another class with the same features or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you need to implement in the code...

1. Open XML SDK. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.
2. You can find various third-party components on the web. Try searching for any of them. Don't want to advertise any.

Comment: ok, it solves the requirement. but still i need to install something (the sdk). i searched and found no other suitable free solution. maybe i will export in csv. but it's not a rich format.

Comment: The Open XML SDK should be installed on the DEV machine only.